# how to write validation in java & in servlet

Tags: java

A JavaBean is a specially constructed Java class written in the Java and coded according to the JavaBeans API specifications.The useBean action declares a JavaBean for use in a JSP. Once declared, the bean becomes a scripting variable that can be accessed by both scripting elements and other custom tags used in the JSP. The full syntax for the useBean tag is as follows −    Here values for the scope attribute can be a page, request, session or application based on your requirement. The value of the id attribute may be any value as a long as it is a unique name among other useBean declarations in the same JSP.

Following are the unique characteristics that distinguish a JavaBean from other Java classes − A JavaBean property is a named attribute that can be accessed by the user of the object. The attribute can be of any Java data type, including the classes that you define.For example, if property name is firstName, your method name would be setFirstName() to write that property. This method is called mutator.

A JavaBean property may be read, write, read only, or write only. JavaBean properties are accessed through two methods in the JavaBean's implementation class −

### Below example code:

```
.image_carousel {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    width: 1200px;
    position: relative;
}

.image_carousel .caroufredsel_wrapper a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.image_carousel img {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 2px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.scrollimg{
    display: block; 
    text-align: left; 
    float: none; 
    position: relative; 
    top: auto; 
    right: auto; 
    bottom: auto; 
    left: auto;
    z-index: auto; 
    width: 1003px; 
    height: 100px; 
    margin: 0px; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
.scrollimg1{
    text-align: left; 
    float: none; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px;
    right: auto; 
    bottom: auto; 
    /*left:60px;*/
    margin: 0px; 
    width: 1004px; 
    height: 100px;
    z-index: auto;
}
```

---

```
body{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    background-color:#eaebed;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;

}
#wrap{
    width:1015px;
    margin:0px auto;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
ul,li,h3,h2{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
#header-container{
    width:1015px;
    margin:0px;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
#header{
    width:1001px;
    margin:0px auto;
    height:90px;
    line-height:90px;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color:#FFF;
    padding-top:10px;

}
.logo{
    background:url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat;
    width:245px;
    height:90px;
    float:left;
}
#nav{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    float:left;
    width:756px;
    height:90px;    
    line-height:90px;
    text-align:center;
}
.navbg{
    background:url(../images/nav_bg.png) repeat-x;
    height:41px;
    line-height:41px;
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-top:49px;
}
.navbg ul{
    list-style:none;
}
.navbg ul li{
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;
    padding-right:30px;
}
.navbg ul li a{
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.navbg ul li a:hover{
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.clr{
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
}
.banner{
    background:url(../images/banner.jpg) no-repeat;
    margin:0px auto;
    width:1001px;
    height:354px;
    margin-top:7px;
        }
        .aboutbanner{
                background:url(../images/banner_aboutus.jpg) no-repeat;
            margin:0px auto;
            width:1001px;
            height:250px;
            margin-top:7px;
        }
        .aboutbanner1{
                background:url(../images/banner_aboutus2.jpg) no-repeat;
            margin:0px auto;
            width:1001px;
            height:250px;
            margin-top:7px;
        }
        .brandsbanner{
                background:url(../images/banner_brands.jpg) no-repeat;
            margin:0px auto;
            width:1001px;
            height:250px;
            margin-top:7px;
        }
        .partnersbanner{
                background:url(../images/banner_partners.jpg) no-repeat;
            margin:0px auto;
            width:1001px;
            height:250px;
            margin-top:7px;
        }
        .contactbanner{
                background:url(../images/banner_contactus.jpg) no-repeat;
            margin:0px auto;
            width:1001px;
            height:250px;
            margin-top:7px;
        }
        .brandscc ul{
            margin-left:20px;
        }
        .brandscc ul li{
            line-height:20px;
            margin-left:50px;
        }
        .vline{
            background:url(../images/verticalline-bg.png) repeat-x;
            height:6px;
            margin:0px auto;
            margin-top:5px;
            width:1001px;

        }
        .vline1{
            background-color:#d18d2e;
            height:2px;
            margin-top:5px;
            width:1001px;
            margin-left:7px;
            }
        #container{
            width:1015px;
            margin:0px auto;    
            background-color:#FFF;
        }
        #column-container{
            width:1001px;
            margin:0px auto;
            height:200px;
            margin-top:30px;
        }
        #column-left{
            width:201px;
            float:left;
        }
        #left-nav ul li{
            list-style:none;
            height:25px;
            background-color:#004572;
            line-height:25px;
            margin-bottom:5px;
            color:#FFF;
            padding-left:10px;
            vertical-align:middle;
        }
        #left-nav ul li a{
            color:#FFF;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        #left-nav ul li a:hover{
            color:#FFF;
            text-decoration:underline;
        }
        #socialnetwork{
            margin-top:20px;
        }
        #socialnetwork .blue{
            height:1px; 
            border-bottom:1px solid #006;
        }
        #socialnetwork ul li{
            list-style:none;

        }
        #column-right{
            width:740px;
            float:left;
            /*background-color:#FF9;*/
            margin-left:32px;   
        }
        #column-right p{
            line-height:20px;
        }
        /*#column-right ul{
            list-style:none;
        }
        #column-right ul li{
            list-style:none;
            display:inline;
        }*/
        .team ul{
            padding-left:17px;
        }
        .team ul li{
                line-height:20px;
        }
        .heading{
            background:url(../images/welcome.png) no-repeat;
            width:476px;
            height:38px;
        }
        h2{
            font-size:14px;
            color:#b4771f;
            line-height:20px;
            letter-spacing:0.1em;
        }
        h3{
            font-size:12px;
            color:#0a3a6d;
            line-height:20px;
            letter-spacing:0.1em;
        }
        #footer-container{  
            background:url(../images/footer_bg.png) repeat-x;
            font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
            font-size:11px;
            color:#FFF;
            height:47px;
            line-height:47px;
        }
        .footer-wrap{
            text-align:center;
            vertical-align:middle;
            margin:0px auto;
            width:1015px;
            height:47px;
        }
        #leftnav{
            height:25px;
            width:200px;
            background-color:#004572;
        }
        #imgscrollheading{
            background:url(../images/scrollerheading.png) no-repeat;
            width:1001px;
            height:40px;
            margin:0px auto;
            margin-top:40px;
        }
        /*scroll images*/
        .imgscroll{
            background:url(../images/scrollimg.jpg) no-repeat;
            width:1001px;
            height:110px;
            margin:0px auto;
            margin-top:10px;

        }
        .present a{
            color:#000;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .present a:hover{
            text-decoration:underline;
            color:#000;
        }
        .projects ul li{
            list-style:circle;
            display:block;
            line-height:20px;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
        /*scroll imges code ends here*/
        /*brans*/
        .subheading{
            color:#0a3a6d;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
        .dottedline{
            border-bottom:1px dotted #0a3a6d;
            height:1px;
            margin-top:10px;
        }
        .ourbrands{

                border:5px solid #1e5a9b;
        }
        .brands ul{
            list-style:none;
        }
        .brands ul li{
            list-style:none;
            display:inline;
        }

        /*banner css*/
        /*form*/
        #formdata fieldset {
            margin:0px;
         padding:0.2em 0.8em;
         border:1px solid #bbb;
        }

        #formdata legend {
         font-weight:bold;
        }

        #formdata label {
         display:block;
        }

        #formdata label span {
         color:#f00;
        }
```

----------htm-------

```
        <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Practice</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/examples.css">        
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="wrap">
        <!-- header container starts here -->
            <div id="header-container">
                <div id="header">
                    <a href="index.htm"><div class="logo"></div></a>
                    <!-- nav starts here -->
                        <div id="nav">
                            <div class="navbg">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="index.htm">HOME</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="aboutus.htm">ABOUT US</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ourbrands.htm">OUR BRANDS</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="ourpartners.htm">OUR PARTNERS</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="projects.htm">SPECIAL PROJECTS</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="contactus.htm">CONTACT US</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- nav ends here -->
                </div>
                        <div class="clr"></div>
                                <div style="overflow:hidden; width:1000px; margin: 10px auto; padding:0 0px;"> 
                        <div>                   
                            <div><img src="images/banner1.jpg"></div>                   

                       </div>               
                </div>
                        <!--  <div class="vline"></div>-->
                        <div class="vline1"></div>
            </div>
        <!-- header container ends here -->
        <div id="container"> 
            <div id="column-container">
                <div id="column-left">
                <div id="left-nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Locations</a><span><img src="images/dots.png" style="float:right; vertical-align:middle; line-height:30px; padding-right:20px; padding-top:8px;"></span></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Download Brochure</a><img src="images/dots.png" style="float:right; vertical-align:middle; line-height:30px; padding-right:20px; padding-top:8px;"></li>
                        <li><a>Featured Product</a><img src="images/dots.png" style="float:right; vertical-align:middle; line-height:30px; padding-right:20px; padding-top:8px;"></li>
                    </ul>           
                 </div>   

            </div> 

                <!-- column left ends here-->  
                <div id="column-right">
                        <div class="heading"></div>
                        <h3>"Global EX-IM Partners is an innovative partnering company that specializes in sourcing and marketing all natural, healthy food and consumer products."</h3>
                        <p>Our goal is to appeal to the "New Generation Lifestyle Consumer"&#8482;. Global Ex-Im's brands cover an array of food categories that include an English Breakfast cereal and granolas, Healthy Pasteurized Peanut Butter Spreads, US grown and produced olive oils and snacks that include Asian inspired rice cakes, seaweed thins, miso soups and popcorns.</p>
        <p>We are a vertically integrated company that sells products through major retail outlets such as ShopRite, White Rose, Trader Joes, Whole Foods and many more.  We also service institutional accounts that include Hospitals, Schools, Universities and major restaurant distribution companies such as US Food Service.</p>
               <div class="brands">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="ourbrands.htm"><img src="images/img-ourbrands.png" style="padding-right:12px;"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="californiaoliveranch.htm"><img src="images/img-featuredproduct.png" style="padding-right:12px;"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/img-locations.png"></a></li>
                    </ul>
               </div>
               </div>

            <!-- column right ends here -->        
            </div> 
            <!-- column container ends here -->
            <div class="clr"></div>
            <div id="imgscrollheading"></div>

            <!-- scrolling imgs starts here -->

            <div>
            <div >
                <div>
                    <div>           
                    <img src="images/is1.png" alt="" width="190" height="66">
                    <img src="images/is2.png" alt="" width="190" height="66">
                    <img src="images/is3.png" alt="" width="190" height="66">
                    <img src="images/is4.png" alt="" width="190" height="66">
                    <img src="images/is5.png" alt="" width="190" height="66">                                      
           </div>
                </div>                      
            </div> 
        </div>


            <!-- scolling imgs ends here -->





         </div>
         <!-- container ends here -->
        </div>  
        <!-- wrap ends here -->  
        <div class="clr"></div>
        <div id="footer-container">
            <div class="footer-wrap">
                Copyright 2017. All rights reserved.
            </div>    
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

---

A JavaBean property is a named attribute that can be accessed by the user of the object. The attribute can be of any Java data type, including the classes that you define.For example, if property name is firstName, your method name would be setFirstName() to write that property. This method is called mutator.      A JavaBean property may be read, write, read only, or write only. JavaBean properties are accessed through two methods in the JavaBean's implementation class −For example, if property name is firstName, your method name would be setFirstName() to write that property. This method is called mutator.For example, if property name is firstName, your method name would be setFirstName() to write that property. This method is called mutator.The useBean action declares a JavaBean for use in a JSP. Once declared, the bean becomes a scripting variable that can be accessed by both scripting elements and other custom tags used in the JSP. The full syntax for the useBean tag is as follows −Here values for the scope attribute can be a page, request, session or application based on your requirement. The value of the id attribute may be any value as a long as it is a unique name among other useBean declarations in the same JSP.Here values for the scope attribute can be a page, request, session or application based on your requirement. The value of the id attribute may be any value as a long as it is a unique name among other useBean declarations in the same JSP.Here values for the scope attribute can be a page, request, session or application based on your requirement. The value of the id attribute may be any value as a long as it is a unique name among other useBean declarations in the same JSP.

```
    enter code here
```

Here values for the scope attribute can be a page, request, session or application based on your requirement. The value of the id attribute may be any value as a long as it is a unique name among other useBean declarations in the same JSP.Here values for the scope attribute can be a page, request, session or application based on your requirement. The value of the id attribute may be any value as a long as it is a unique name among other useBean declarations in the same JSP.Here values for the scope attribute can be a page, request, session or application based on your requirement. The value of the id attribute may be any value as a long as it is a unique name among other useBean declarations in the same JSP.Here values for the scope attribute can be a page, request, session or application based on your requirement. The value of the id attribute may be any value as a long as it is a unique name among other useBean declarations in the same JSP.Here values for the scope attribute can be a page, request, session or application based on your requirement. The value of the id attribute may be any value as a long as it is a unique name among other useBean declarations in the same JSP.

Comment: You can look into    http://www.pskills.in/servlet/validation-of-form.jsp this link

Comment: Please see [ask] for some guidelines on how to structure your question more appropriately. This will help future readers to be able to receive benefit from your question and the answers that come, as well as it will help the answerers give more accurate help. One of the details that are outlined in the How To Ask guidelines is to not start a question with code.